# How do I find/generate the registry key name associated with a program?

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-registry

A bit of background information on why I'm asking this question and my goal:

I'm trying to get the volume mixer to save my settings but it doesn't work for certain apps, namely Windows Media Player. I lower the volume to half, but when I close and reopen the app it goes back to max volume.

After a bit of research I found that Windows saves or automatically generates these values in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore`
and that I could use [AppAudioConfig](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_audio_config.html) to interpret these values.

However, the process for Windows Media Player did not show up at all in the list of applications in AppAudioConfig, which meant Windows was not generating a registry key for it.

I'm trying to solve the problem by manually adding a registry key and maybe copying the values over, but the names associated with each program are effectively random to me. For example, the registry key that was generated with Firefox for me was `c69570e8_0`.

Screenshot of AppAudioConfig
[image]

Screenshot of registry
[image]

How do I find/generate the associated registry key name for an executable?

Answer (score 0):

As you don't mind using 3rd party apps to accomplish your goal, might I suggest this awesome little tool to control your volume in Windows: **[EarTrumpet](https://eartrumpet.app/)**

It's what the Windows Volume Mixer should have been like to begin with..

By the way, have you tried changing the volume in Windows Media Player itself instead of the Volume Mixer? It seems to store this as well. I also tested if Windows Volume Mixer would store settings and it did, but unfortunately also no registry seems to be created at the location you provided...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, EarTrumpet doesn't work. It's one of the first things I've tried since it was brought up in discussion while I was looking for solutions. I think it uses the same mechanisms as the native settings anyway. I have tried changing the volume in the app itself and it works, yes. It's just that it isn't enough.

Comment: Additionally, windows is quite weird with that registry location. For some people, all they needed to do was create that registry key and settings would save without windows populating it. Have you tried using AppAudioConfig and seeing the various process that would be linked to the registry entries? Additionally, no new entries are created unless u change the volume settings from their default. You have to change the volume through the Mixer while the app is open and then restart it for the entries to be generated iirc.